# TeamCity agent returning 502 bad gateway

Tags: amazon-ec2, teamcity

I'm getting this when starting up a TeamCity agent. To expose TC Server on EC2 I'm using Application request routing, Created a Server Farm and route 80 to 8080 internally. I can see mention of Port 9090 in below logs - I'm wondering if I would need to create a second application request route for 9090 - I haven't seen mention of this in any docs - anyone have XP with this?

```
[2014-02-09 07:31:35,994]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on
server http://team.xxxx.com.au, AgentDetails{Name='WIN-IXXX',
AgentId=null, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=
[10.xxx.xxx.xxx, 54.xxx.xxx.xxx], Port=9090, Version='27767', PluginsVersion='NA',  
 AvailableRunners=[], AvailableVcs=[], AuthorizationToken=''} 

[2014-02-09 07:32:08,567]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Call
http://team.xxxx.com.au/RPC2 buildServer.registerAgent3:
org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientException: Server returned incorrect status code: 502 Bad  
Gateway
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TeamCity server needs to be able to open HTTP connections to the agent via the `ownPort` property of the `buildAgent.properties` file. That port is, by default, `9090`.

You can read more here:

[TeamCity - Setting Up Additional Build Agents](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD5/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-NecessaryOSandenvironmentpermissions)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had 9090 open in the security groups for both agent and server but had the firewall on the agent - Turned off now its great - thanks for the tip.